# how to give position to widget based on stack's maximum container not parent of stack's container?

Tags: flutter

I am trying a demo for understanding stack,

setting position to green at bottom 0 right 0 , it set at stack's parent container's right bottom,

I want to move green container to red's bottom right corner

[image]

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 500,
          width: 350,
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            children: [
              Container(
                height:300,
                width: 300,
                color: Colors.red,

              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.green,
               
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),

);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `red` box as parent for `green` box. The quick fix would be to add `Stack()` as `child` for `red` box and then giving `green` box inside that.

```
Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Container(
      height: 500,
      width: 350,
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        children: [
          Container(
            height:300,
            width: 300,
            color: Colors.red,
            // Here new stack inside red box
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              children:[
                // green box
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ]
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: is there no any other solution, so the sequences remain the same

Comment: If you need it in the same sequence you need to calculate the heights and on the basis of heights, you need to position them. But here you are giving constant height. It will cause problem with variable heights